How to use and interpret results from glmer() in R, when the predicted risks are lower than observed
I previously asked this question on stack overflow, but was redirected here.
I have a dataframe of patients, with an outcome of cancer flagged, and other variables to be used as covariates (around 20 of these). The dataframe is made up of multiple cohorts which are flagged in a single column with a number to indicate cohort membership.



patid
cancer
age
sex
smoking_status
bmi_cat
cohort




00001
0
56
1
2
1
1


00002
0
54
1
1
2
1


00003
0
70
2
1
2
2



etc.
To allow varying interaction with age, I have one hot-encoded the cohort variable as in single-cohort models, some were found to have interaction with age.
My model form is something like:
glmer(cancer~ns(age_idate,df=3)+ns(age_idate,df=3):(cohort_6,cohort_4,cohort_9)+cohort_6+cohort_4+cohort_1+cohort_2+sex+bmi_cat+smoking_status+fatigue...etc.
+(1|patid),
family=binomial,
data=model_data,
nAGQ=0,
control=glmerControl(calc.derivs=FALSE)

When I use predict() to get predicted risk of cancer in the original model_data, I achieve reasonable predictions based on the results of my individual models and clinical knowledge.
However, I need to get predicted risk simply at each age (30-100) and sex (male,female) combination, rather than on an individual patient level, for each of the cohorts.
I create a dataframe of all age and sex combinations, and then append all other variables set to their base value (i.e. 0 in a 2 level factor), except from the cohort I am interested in, which I set to 1.



age
sex
smoking_status
bmi_cat
cohort_1
cohort_2




30
1
0
0
1
0


31
1
0
0
1
0


32
1
0
0
1
0



etc.
The code I use to predict is:
model_pred_cohort_1 <- 
marginaleffects::predictions(
model=mixed_effects_mod,
newdata=grouped_data,
re.form=NA,
type='response'
)

When I make predictions on this dataframe, the predicted risk for each age is much lower than expected. I've also tried adding in the patid variable with different random values, as I am not sure if this is needed, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.
My question is: is this the correct use of this model type, and is there a reason my model is outputting much lower risks than observed?
If I simply look in my model_data, filter by a specific cohort, and look at the proportion of patients with cancer vs not, it gives a higher value then the same combination of predicted values, but only when predicting onto each specific age and sex combination, not if I am just getting predicted risk for each patient in the population.
I have been pointed to documentation on the emmeans() function, but am unsure how to apply it to my use case. Is this something that would solve my low predict value problem?
Sorry if the question is not clear or more information is required.

Yes, this is a fairly well-known issue; back-transforming the population mean neglects the effect of the variation around the population mean, so the result on the original data (probability) scale is biased due to Jensen's inequality. The emmeans package offers a reasonable (approximate) way to correct this bias.
See also this Stack Overflow question.
The transformations vignette from the emmeans package explains:

So far, we have discussed ideas related to back-transforming results as a simple way of expressing results on the same scale as the response. In particular, means obtained in this way are known as generalized means; for example, a log transformation of the response is associated with geometric means. When the goal is simply to make inferences about which means are less than which other means, and a response transformation is used, it is often acceptable to present estimates and comparisons of these generalized means ...


... [We may need (or want)] to make a bias adjustment when we back-transform, because any nonlinear transformation biases the expected values of statistical quantities. More specifically, suppose that we have a response $Y$
and the transformed response is $U$. To back-transform, we use $Y=h(U)$; and using a Taylor approximation,
$$
Y \approx h(\eta)+h′(\eta)(U−\eta)+(1/2)h′′(η)(U−\eta)^2 ,
$$
so that $E(Y)≈h(\eta)+(1/2)h′′(\eta)\textrm{Var}(U)$. This shows that the amount of needed bias adjustment is approximately $(1/2)h′′(\eta)\sigma^2$ where σ is the error SD in the model for U. It depends on σ, and the larger this is, the greater the bias adjustment is needed. This second-order bias adjustment is what is currently used in the emmeans package when bias-adjustment is requested. There are better or exact adjustments for certain cases, and future updates may incorporate some of those.

(It might make sense that the marginaleffects or modelbased packages would also provide such functionality, but at present they don't, see here, here, ...)

Thanks for your response. If my model output is stored as mixed_effects_mod, which would be the object in emmeans(), what would the correct form be for my other variables? I tried playing around with it but couldn't seem to get it to work. Do I need to use the ref_grid() function to specify the grid iterates over age and sex? I also couldn't quite understand the form I should use for that function. Do you have any advice? I'm quite new to all of this!

To clarify, my error for emmeans() revolves around 'the rows of your requested reference grid would exceed the limit of 10000", which part of my model would be causing this?

@freya questions specific to coding for emmeans might best be asked on Stack Overflow. We try to keep a primary focus on statistical issues on Cross Validated. When you ask for this help on Stack Overflow, provide some information about the data, the model, and the code you used for emmeans that produced the error. I suspect that you specified too fine a grid for continuous variables or for combinations of variables.
